# Linear and Topological closure

Tags: linear-algebra, general-topology

I would like to know what is the relationship (if there is any) between linear and topological closure?

Comment: Are you interested in generalizations that have each as a special case, or are you interested in how linear spans (or convex hulls) relate to topological closure in spaces where both are defined, such as in normed spaces or topological vector spaces?

Comment: I would say that I am primarily interested in the second case, that is, their relation within a more concrete example.

Answer (score 1):

An operation on members of set is said to be closed if that operation produces another member of that set. In topology the operation is that of taking limits. In linear algebra the operation is linear combination, the closure of a set of vectors is the smallest subset of the vector space that includes that set of vectors and is closed under linear combination.